# Forcing jQuery validator to validate a single element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, x-editable

On an edit page, I am using http://jqueryvalidation.org/ to validate a form.

```
//validate object set using external file linked to page
var myValidateObj = {
    "rules": {
        "foo": {"required": true,"maxlength": 45,"minlength": 2},
        "bar": {"maxlength": 45},
    },
    "messages": {
        "foo": {"required": "Foo is required.",},
        "bar": {"maxlength": "bla bla."},
    }
};

var validator=$("#myform").validate({
    rules: myValidateObj.rules,
    messages: myValidateObj.messages,
});

<form id="myForm">
    Foo: <input type="text" name="foo" />
    Bar: <input type="text" name="bar" />
    <input type="submit" value="SAVE">
</form>
```

On another page, I am displaying the values of the previously described edit page, and allowing inline editing using http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/.  The validation rules and messages still apply, but now are only needed to validate a single field.  Assuming the `myValidateObj` object exists on this page, can it be used to validate a single field?  For instance, within the editable validate callback, how can `myValidateObj` be used to validate `foo` and return the appropriate message upon not passing validation?

```
$('#foo').editable({
    type: 'text',
    validate: function(value) {
        //How do I use myValidateObj to validate foo and return applicable message???
    }
});

Name: <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="foo"><?php echo($foo); ?></a>
Bla: <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="bar"><?php echo($bar); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.valid()` method can be used to force an immediate validation test of a single element.

```
$('#foo').valid();
```

http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

---

**FYI**:

The `.validate()` method is *only* used for ***initializing*** the plugin on your form, not for triggering tests.  Therefore, you still need to call `.validate()` once within DOM ready before you can use `.valid()`.

Comment: Thanks Sparky,  Not sure how this would work.  Please see https://jsfiddle.net/he9Lnz3m/1/.  Thank you

Comment: @user1032531, lots of issues in that jsFiddle.  1) There is no `<form>` 2) You cannot validate an `<a>` element. 3) You never called the `.validate()` method anyplace.

Comment: Thanks Sparky.  A `<form>` does exist, but only exists after the initial page load.  Note trying to validate an `<a>` element, only an `<input>`.  Did call the `.validate()` method, but only in the callback.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569394/validate-dynamically-generated-form-with-jquery-validator.  EDIT.  See you just responded to that post.  Thanks!  Will get right back!

Comment: Don't know why I added the blurb about getting right back...  The `<a>` is replaced with a dynamically created `<form>` which contains an `<input>`.  I did call the `.validate()` method, but only in the callback.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Turned out my problem was that the form was not appended to the body.  Can't hide, but could style off the page.  Thanks

Comment: This is not working for hidden fields, even though I added the class "required", any idea?

Comment: @WaqasBukhary - because hidden fields are ignored by default.  Refer to the docs and lookup the `ignore` option.