# Validate dynamically generated form with jQuery Validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Sorry for keep asking this, but I just can't figure it out.  I've reduced the question to just the bare minimum.

How can I validate a dynamically generated form?  Below is my attempt, but as seen, it shows up as passing validation.

https://jsfiddle.net/j2pgobze/1/

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="bademail" >
</form>
<button id="validate">validate</button>

var myValidateObj = {
     rules: {
         email: {
             email: true
         }
     }
 };

 $(function () {

     jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
         debug: true,
         success: "valid"
     });

     $('#validate').click(function () {

         //Validate the traditional form
         var validate1 = $('#myForm').validate(myValidateObj);
         console.log('Option 1', $('#myForm'), $('#email'), $('#email').val(), validate1.element('#email'), $('#email').valid(), $('#myForm').valid());

         //Validate dynamically created form
         var input = $('<input />', {
             type: 'text',
             name: 'email',
             value: 'bademail'
         });
         //input.prop('value', 'bademail');
         var form = $('<form />').append(input);
         var validate = form.validate(myValidateObj);
         console.log('Option 2', form, input, $('#email').val(), validate.element(input), input.valid(), form.valid());
     });

 });
```

Comment: Mistake #1... putting `.validate()` within a `click` handler.  I also don't understand why you are creating another form within the click handler of the first form.

Comment: @Sparky.  Because the form doesn't exist upon page load.  I agree the part about `$('#myForm').validate(myValidateObj);` doesn't make sense, but was just included as an example.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542425/forcing-jquery-validator-to-validate-a-single-element and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566417/access-x-editable-dynamically-generated-form-or-input for some history.  Appreciate any help!

Comment: I answered the first one and you stopped responding to me.  I can only address the issues in each specific question.  I cannot be expected to look at somebody's several different questions and put the whole project together.  That being said, I would also be willing to post an answer here, but it will only address the specific problems in this particular question.

Comment: Sparky!  Thank you.  Sorry, have a day job and just got back.  Also sorry for the different questions (however, I think they were different, but might be confusing things).  I am okay with an answer to this particular question.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sparky  Also, clarification of intent.  I define some jQuery Validator rules but only want to do so in one location to keep consistent.  First then are used on a traditional form.  Perfect.  Then wish to use the same rules with inline editing.  Thanks again!!!

Comment: Yes, understood.  I would appreciate some conclusion to the other question I've answered.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sparky  Added some conclusion, however, my question in the earlier post was a bit convoluted.  Appreciate any help.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The button needs to be inside the `form` and be a `type="submit"` in order for the plugin to capture the click.
2. Do not put `.validate()` within a `click` handler (See item 1).  It's only used to initialize the plugin on a form.  Exception, below we are creating the new form within a `click` handler and then immediately calling `.validate()` on the new form.

With these two small changes, the validation on the static form is working: [jsfiddle.net/j2pgobze/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/j2pgobze/3/)

3. I rewrote your DOM manipulation code for clarity.  I simply duplicated the HTML for the form and gave it a new ID: http://jsfiddle.net/zem84tfp/

---

```
$(function () {

     // INITIALIZE plugin on the traditional form
     var validate1 = $('#myForm').validate(myValidateObj);

     $('#newform').one('click', function () {

         // code here to create new form; give it new ID
         // do not duplicate ID on anything else

         // INITIALIZE plugin on the new form
         var validate = $('#myForm2').validate(myValidateObj);
     });

});
```

Comment: Wow, that was weird.  I didn't even see your answer when I posted a comment back to you.  Your approach certainly seems to do what I asked.  Don't know if it will meet my objectives yet and will need to test.  Thanks for your help.